# Connection Error with Django/Celery and CloudAMQP/Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, celery, cloudamqp

I have a Django app that I've already deployed to Heroku. This app uses Celery for message queuing and I've run it locally using RabbitMQ without incident.

Unfortunately, when I went to deploy this baby to Heroku, I found that the RabbitMQ addon wasn't available and that I'd have to use CloudAMQP. The documentation for both CloudAMQP and Heroku lead me to believe that I can use Celery (even though they recommend Pika), but when I try to deploy, I get gnarly connection errors for both my scheduler and worker processes. Here are the exact errors:

```
2012-07-09T16:46:22+00:00 app[scheduler.1]: [2012-07-09 11:46:22,234: ERROR/Beat] Celerybeat: Connection error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 2.0 seconds...
2012-07-09T16:46:23+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2012-07-09 11:46:23,852: ERROR/MainProcess] Consumer: Connection Error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 2 seconds...
```

I should note that my Heroku config vars DO have a CLOUDAMQP_URL, so that shouldn't be a problem?

I would appreciate it if anyone who has used CloudAMQP with Django/Heroku could give me some  guidance about how to make sure that Celery can connect with the broker.

Comment: How many working dynos do you have?

Answer (score 6):

You're probably exceeding the 3 concurrent connections limit of the free plan. Set the  [BROKER_POOL_LIMIT](http://celery.github.com/celery/configuration.html#std:setting-BROKER_POOL_LIMIT) to 1 and it should work a lot better.

Comment: Once you have exceeded your connection limit, is there an easy way to reset your connections to 0? Resetting my dynos does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: @theStreaker123 I use `heroku restart myworker -a myapp` it restarts my workers.

Comment: @Jeff This is two years late, but you need to [make sure you have heartbeats setup](https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/python.html) and then force kill your connections that do not contain heartbeats. You can also set CloudAMQP heartbeats by appending ``?heartbeat=30`` to your CAMQP broker URL but to my knowledge it is undocumented.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have this at the top of your `settings.py` file.

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for posting an answer.